# Android Conscrypt doesn't throw InvalidKeyException

Tags: android, encryption, openssl, cryptography

When generating keys of different key sizes (not specifying provider and having [Conscrypt](https://github.com/google/conscrypt) chosen by default) and then using `KeyAgreement` to generate a shared secret, I would expect an `InvalidKeyException` to be thrown.

After testing on 3 Android devices, I noticed on the device running Android 9 an `InvalidKeyException` *is* correctly thrown.

However, on devices running Android 6 and Android 7, `InvalidKeyException` *is not* thrown.

Here is the test and code being run in an instrumented test:

**Test**:

```
@Test
public void generateECDHSharedSecret_returnsNull_ifKeySizesDifferent() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    KeyPairGenerator deviceKeyGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
    deviceKeyGenerator.initialize(224);
    KeyPairGenerator serverKeyGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
    serverKeyGenerator.initialize(256);
    PublicKey serverPublicKey = deviceKeyGenerator.generateKeyPair().getPublic();
    PrivateKey devicePrivateKey = serverKeyGenerator.generateKeyPair().getPrivate();
    byte[] sharedSecret = ServerKeyAgreement.generateECDHSharedSecret(devicePrivateKey, serverPublicKey);

    Assert.assertNull(sharedSecret);
}
```

**Implementation**:

```
package com.bla.bla;

import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;

import javax.crypto.KeyAgreement;

class ServerKeyAgreement {
    static byte[] generateECDHSharedSecret(PrivateKey privateKey, PublicKey publicKey) {
        try {
            KeyAgreement keyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH");
            keyAgreement.init(privateKey);
            keyAgreement.doPhase(publicKey, true);
            return keyAgreement.generateSecret();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
                InvalidKeyException |
                RuntimeException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Why doesn't `InvalidKeyException` get thrown on Android 6 & 7, and is the shared secret generated actually valid?**

Comment: It's probably just a bug. The shared secret would not be "valid" in the sense that the peer will not generate the same shared secret, so encryption/decryption will fail.

Comment: This may still be a serious issue, that may indicate worse bugs when it comes to ECDH with standard curves. For the P-224 and P-256 parameters the receiver is required to test that the public key point lies on the curve, or the result may not be valid (one of the major reasons why the Curve25519 is popular, because this isn't required for that curve to be secure). Anyway, returning a wrong answer instead of throwing an exception already indicates a serious bug to me.

Comment: Note that Android crypto has a way more spotty history anyway compared to Java SE. The SHA1PRNG and Bouncy Castle issues clearly showed incompetence in earlier versions.